# Prove the inequality $9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geq 8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove the inequality $9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geq 8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$

I tried by first using AM-HM inequality on $a, b, c$ to get the following result.

$\frac{a+b+c}3 \geq \frac 3{\frac 1a+\frac1b+\frac1c}$

$\implies (a+b+c)(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c) \geq 9$

$\implies (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \geq 9abc$

Also I used the inequality

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geq 8abc$

But then I am not able to proceed further. Can someone please help me.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2205355p16644450 on AoPS.

Comment: I believe, you've missed something in problem statement. Check case $a=-1$, $b=-1$, $c=0$.

Comment: While we use a.m.-g.m.-inequality we always consider $a, b, c$ for $\mathbb{R_{> 0}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - 8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$ = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - 8abc$$
$$\ge0$$

because $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc$

and $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \ge 8abc$ by AM-GM: $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=abc+\dots+bca\ge 8\sqrt[8]{a^8b^8c^8}$.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start my solution, I want to say that the proof you have just showed was nice try but it's hard to prove the claim. If you want to show that $A>B$, it's meaningless to show that $A>C$ and $B>C$.

Alright, so I'll show my solution.

\begin{align}
& \text{Claim. } 9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geq 8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca). \\
& \text{pf)} \\
\ \\
\text{Claim} & \Leftrightarrow 9\Bigg(\sum_{sym} a^2b + 2abc \Bigg) \geq 8 \Bigg( \sum_{sym} a^2b + 3abc \Bigg) \\
& \Leftrightarrow \sum_{sym} a^2b \geq 6abc \\
& \Leftrightarrow a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+ab^2+bc^2+ca^2 \geq 6abc \\
& \Leftrightarrow \dfrac {a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+ab^2+bc^2+ca^2} {6} \geq \sqrt[6]{a^2b \cdot b^2c \cdot c^2a \cdot ab^2 \cdot bc^2 \cdot ca^2} \\
& \Rightarrow \text{Proved by AM-GM Inequality.}
\end{align}